# Vue function calling issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am downloading PDF using mPDF using following code, but not able to download on live server.

```
<button  class="btn btn-secondary float-right bar-btn " @click="generatePdf()"><strong>Download Report</strong><i class="icon-back"></i><div class="loader"></div></button>

generatePdf() {
            axios({
                url: '/api/dummy-pdf',
                method: 'GET',
                responseType: 'blob', // important
            }).then((response) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            });

        },
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos No i am not getting any error, even cant see any comment in console just to ensure whether in my function or not. While i can see comments in console on local